# Why in dataTable information is read from the database, But they are not displayed in the dataTable

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

dataTable information is read from the database, But they are not displayed in the dataTable I use inspect to see the information, but the table is not displayed at all What's wrong?
The code is as follows

```
public PartialViewResult OnGetViewAllPartial()
{
    lstLevel =  _CourseLevelApplication.GetCourseLevelForDisplay();
    return new PartialViewResult
    {
        ViewName = "_ViewAll",
        ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<IEnumerable<CoursLevelViewModel>>(ViewData, lstLevel)      
    };
}


   <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>                                  
                                <th>title</th>                         
                                <th>action</th>
                                
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                <tr>                                             
                                    <td>@item.Id</td>
                                    <td>@item.Title</td> 
        
                                    <td>
                                      <a onclick="jQueryModalGet('?handler=CreateOrEdit&id=@item.Id','Edit level')" class="btn btn-info text-white"> Edit</a>
                                    <form method="post" asp-page="Index" asp-route-id="@item.Id" asp-page-handler="Delete" onsubmit="return jQueryModalDelete(this)" class="d-inline">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger text-white"> Delete</button>
                                    </form>
                                        
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

@section Scripts {
<script src="~/AdminTheme/assets/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/AdminTheme/assets/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#datatable').dataTable();
    });

</script>
```

}

Comment: Did you check the browser console for javascript/jquery errors?

Comment: Yes, no error is displayed

Comment: without using PartialViewResult Works ، But I want a PartialViewResult

Comment: Ah. Then my guess would be that `$(document).ready` is never called. Use a function to (re)create the DT after loading is done instead of document ready.

Comment: I'm weak in JavaScript. Please write the function you say

Comment: `function startDataTable() { $('#datatable').dataTable(); }` and call that when the Partial has finished loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting these into the head section into the layout page.

```
<script src="~/AdminTheme/assets/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/AdminTheme/assets/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Deleting a class solved the problem